# How to use aggregation within a case statement?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm working on a use case where in I need to use aggregation within a case statement. Below is the logic for the same

```
If the column1 matches column2 then data else array_join(array_agg(data), ';')
```

Below is my input dataset -

```
  column1   column2
      de    decore
      uk    ukcore
      es    escore
      ca    cacore
      es    escore
      uk    ukcore
      ww    a1sz
      ww    a1qu
      ww    a1pp
      ww    a1kv
      ww    a1ba
      ww    a15j
      pl    plcore
```

Below is my required output

```
column1 column2
    de  decore
    uk  ukcore
    es  escore
    ca  cacore
    es  escore
    uk  ukcore
    ww  a1sz;a1qu;a1pp;a1kv;a1ba;a15j
    pl  plcore
```

I tried using below queries -
**Query1**

```
Select column2,
       case
         when trim(lower(split(column2,'xyz')[1])) = trim(lower(column1)) then column2 else array_join(array_agg(column2), ';') end as column2
from my_table
group by column2, column1
```

**Query2**

```
Select column2,
       case
         when trim(lower(column1)) like CONCAT( '%', trim(lower(column2)), '%') then column2 else array_join(array_agg(column2), ';') end as column2
from my_table
group by column2, column1
```

But none of them are working. Please help

Comment: For your example data, you could just `group by column2`. Please provide a dataset that really demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Edited the input data

Comment: `group by column2` would still solve the problem. Probably you need to add more rows...

Comment: Why are you grouping by 2 columns if the result clearly shows that it was grouped by 1 (`column2`)?

Comment: @GuruStron It is because of the case statement.

Comment: why are there duplicates in your data?  if you don't have duplicates, then `Select column1, string_agg(column2, ';') as testcol
from my_table
group by column1` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure what is actually needed, the desired output from provided sample data can be achieved just with:

```sql
Select column2,
    array_join(array_agg(data), ';')
from my_table
group by column2;
```

But if you want some conditional logic, you need to use aggregate function like [`arbitrary`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#arbitrary) to select one value from the group (I use `if` instead of CASE, it is basically the same but with more readable syntax):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(column1, column2)     AS (
    values ('de', 'decore'),
        ('uk', 'ukcore'),
        ('es', 'escore'),
        ('ca', 'cacore'),
        ('es', 'escore'),
        ('uk', 'ukcore'),
        ('ww', 'a1sz'),
        ('ww', 'a1qu'),
        ('ww', 'a1pp'),
        ('ww', 'a1kv'),
        ('ww', 'a1ba'),
        ('ww', 'a15j'),
        ('pl', 'plcore')
)

select column1, if(grp_cnd, array_join(array_agg(column2), ';'), arbitrary(column2)) column2
from (
    select *,
       if(
            column2 like trim(column1) || '%', false, true) grp_cnd  
    from dataset)
group by column1, grp_cnd;
```

Output:

| column2 | data |
| --- | --- |
| usa | 5 |
| ww | 2;7 |

**UPD**

Update to use new data (with small refactoring):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(column1, column2)     AS (
    values ('de', 'decore'),
        ('uk', 'ukcore'),
        ('es', 'escore'),
        ('ca', 'cacore'),
        ('es', 'escore'),
        ('uk', 'ukcore'),
        ('ww', 'a1sz'),
        ('ww', 'a1qu'),
        ('ww', 'a1pp'),
        ('ww', 'a1kv'),
        ('ww', 'a1ba'),
        ('ww', 'a15j'),
        ('pl', 'plcore')
)

-- query
select column1, if(grp_cnd, array_join(array_agg(column2), ';'), arbitrary(column2)) column2
from (
    select *,
       if(
            -- use here appropriate condition
            column2 like trim(column1) || '%', false, true) grp_cnd  
    from dataset)
group by column1, grp_cnd;
```

Output:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| ca | cacore |
| de | decore |
| uk | ukcore |
| es | escore |
| pl | plcore |
| ww | a1sz;a1qu;a1pp;a1kv;a1ba;a15j |

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've edited my input and output with actual data. Can you please check once?

Comment: @djm see the updated please.

Comment: @djm when you are running the sample? It runs fine for me. Please provide more info.

Comment: Getting all values for every rows like `escore;ukcore;cacore;a1sz;a1qu;a1pp;a1kv;a1ba;a15j;decore;plcore` Also in your output i see some duplicate rows. Any reason?

Comment: @djm for dupes - misunderstood the update, the original approach should work.

Comment: @djm as for why you have the merge - as I wrote in the comment in the query - you need to update the condition according to actual data.

Comment: @djm try running the exact query in the update and figure out what is different in your data.

Comment: Can I ping you personally?

Comment: @djm yes sure, why not. Where do you prefer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254300/discussion-between-djm-and-guru-stron).